# How can I get my timer to accurately reflect the input durations I've specified?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

The pomodoro timer I'm writing has a set of different durations you're able to set for the various sessions into an input that it reads and then, according to the corresponding session, start the timer. However, my timer, by default, always starts at 5 minutes.

[image: Timer showing off session I've set and what it defaults to]

I've tracked down a number of places to see how the code responds by console logging the areas but to no effect. They all log fine for the most part. Is there anything I'm missing?

Files for the popup:

```js
// popup.js

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let timerButton = document.getElementById("timerButton");
  let resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton");
  let durationSelect = document.getElementById("durationSelect");
  let timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput");
  let timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  let isTimerRunning = false;
  let isTimerPaused = false;



  let savedValue = localStorage.getItem(durationSelect.value);
  if (savedValue) {
    timeInput.value = savedValue;
  }

  console.log('Attaching change event listener to timeInput'); // test
  timeInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
    let selectedDuration = durationSelect.value;
    localStorage.setItem(selectedDuration, timeInput.value);
    console.log(`New value for ${selectedDuration}: ${timeInput.value}`); // test
  });

  console.log('Attaching change event listener to durationSelect'); // test
  durationSelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
    let selectedDuration = durationSelect.value;
    savedValue = localStorage.getItem(selectedDuration);
    console.log(`Retrieved value for ${selectedDuration}: ${savedValue}`); // test
    if (savedValue) {
      timeInput.value = savedValue;
    } else {
      timeInput.value = ""; // Clear input if no saved value
    }
  });

  // Get the current duration from the background script and display it
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getDuration" }, (response) => {
    timer.innerText = response.duration;
  });

  chrome.storage.sync.get(["isTimerRunning", "isTimerPaused"], (data) => {
    isTimerRunning = data.isTimerRunning;
    isTimerPaused = data.isTimerPaused;
    if (isTimerRunning) {
      timerButton.textContent = isTimerPaused ? "Resume" : "Pause";
    }
  });

  let workDurationInput = document.getElementById("workDuration");
  let shortBreakDurationInput = document.getElementById("shortBreakDuration");
  let longBreakDurationInput = document.getElementById("longBreakDuration");

  workDurationInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      workDuration: parseInt(workDurationInput.value, 10) * 60,
    });
  });

  shortBreakDurationInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      shortBreakDuration: parseInt(shortBreakDurationInput.value, 10) * 60,
    });
  });

  longBreakDurationInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      longBreakDuration: parseInt(longBreakDurationInput.value, 10) * 60,
    });
  });

  timerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!isTimerRunning) {
      let duration = parseInt(
        document.getElementById("workDuration").value,
        10
      );
      if (duration < 1) {
        alert("Work duration must be at least 1 minute.");
        return;
      }

      duration *= 60;
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "startTimer", duration: duration });
      timerButton.textContent = "Pause";
      isTimerRunning = true;
    } else if (!isTimerPaused) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "pauseTimer" });
      timerButton.textContent = "Resume";
      isTimerPaused = true;
    } else {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "resumeTimer" });
      timerButton.textContent = "Pause";
      isTimerPaused = false;
    }

    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      isTimerRunning: isTimerRunning,
      isTimerPaused: isTimerPaused,
    });
  });

  resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "resetTimer" });
    timerButton.textContent = "Start";
    isTimerRunning = false;
    isTimerPaused = false;
    // Store button state
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      isTimerRunning: isTimerRunning,
      isTimerPaused: isTimerPaused,
    });
  });

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === "updateTimer") {
      // Update the timer display
      timer.innerText = request.duration;
    }
  });

  // Get the remaining duration from storage and display it
  chrome.storage.sync.get("remainingDuration", (data) => {
    timer.innerText = data.remainingDuration;
  });
});
```

```html
// popup.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" />
    <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>

    <div>
      <label for="durationSelect">Select Duration:</label>
      <select id="durationSelect" name="durationSelect">
        <option id="workDuration">Pomodoro</option>
        <option id="shortBreakDuration">Short Break</option>
        <option id="longBreakDuration">Long Break</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="time" id="timeInput" name="timeInput">
    </div>
    <p id="timer"</p>
    <div id="Buttons">
      <button id="timerButton">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
          play_arrow
        </span>
      </button>
      <button id="resetButton">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
          restart_alt
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Background/service worker file:

```js
let timer = null;
let duration = 0;
let isPaused = false;

const Session = {
  Work: 'work',
  ShortBreak: 'shortBreak',
  LongBreak: 'longBreak',
};

let currentSession = Session.Work;
let workSessionsCompleted = 0;

function updateDurationsFromStorage(callback) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['workDuration', 'shortBreakDuration', 'longBreakDuration', 'duration'], (data) => {
    workDuration = data.workDuration;
    shortBreakDuration = data.shortBreakDuration;
    longBreakDuration = data.longBreakDuration;
    duration = data.duration;
    callback();
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'startTimer') {
    updateDurationsFromStorage( () => {
      duration = request.duration;
      console.log("Duration set in startTimer message handler:", duration); // test
      isPaused = false;
    startTimer();
    });
  } else if (request.action === 'pauseTimer') {
    isPaused = true;
  } else if (request.action === 'resumeTimer') {
    isPaused = false;
  } else if(request.action === 'resetTimer') {
    clearInterval(timer);
    duration = 0;
    isPaused = false;
    currentSession = Session.Work;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateTimer', duration: formatDuration(duration)});
  } else if (request.action === 'getDuration') {
    sendResponse({duration: formatDuration(duration)});
  }

  return true;
});



function startTimer() {
  if (timer) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (!isPaused) {
      duration--;
      console.log("Duration updated in setInterval function:", duration); // test
      if (duration <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        switch (currentSession) {
          case Session.Work:
            console.log("work duration: " + workDuration); // test for case
            console.log("duration " + duration);
            workSessionsCompleted++;  
            if (workSessionsCompleted === 4) {
              currentSession = Session.LongBreak;
              duration = longBreakDuration;
            } else {
              currentSession = Session.ShortBreak;
              duration = shortBreakDuration;
            }
            break;
          case Session.ShortBreak:
            console.log("This is the short break: " + shortBreakDuration); // test for case
          case Session.LongBreak:
            console.log("This is the long break: " + longBreakDuration); // test for case
            currentSession = Session.Work;
            duration = workDuration;
            break;
        }
        startTimer();
      }
      // Store the remaining duration
      chrome.storage.sync.set({remainingDuration: duration});
    }

    // Send a message to the popup to update the display
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'updateTimer', duration: formatDuration(duration)});
  }, 1000);
}

function formatDuration(duration) {
  let minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
  let seconds = duration % 60;
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  return String(minutes) + ':' + String(seconds);
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("workDuration").value` is "Pomodoro", not a number. Debug your code interactively in devtools with breakpoints. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: It should be a number, yeah. The time input should return a number and the .value accesses that. I have been looking at both the background and popup devtools to make sure I wasn't missing anything. But I think I've realised something, the time input works on HH:MM when I really need MM:SS. But even then, maybe it isn't reading that in the first place?

Comment: My point is that you're using the wrong id of a different element. Use devtools to debug the code interactively where you can inspect the variables visually.